# Function to Randomly Change Background Color with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styling

I am trying to define a function that changess the background color of the homepage when a user clicks a button.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      quotes: [], 
      selectedQuoteIndex: null,
      background: 'white'
    }   
    this.changeBackground = this.changeBackground.bind(this);
  }

  changeBackground() {
    return random(backgroundColor);
  }        

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.changeBackground}/>
    )   
  }
}
```

I do not know where to put return background color.

Comment: Your example seems incomplete and has syntax errors (maybe that's why it isn't working). Where are `random` and `backgroundColor` defined? Where are you reading `this.state.background`? `onClick(changeBackground)` is not valid syntax inside an JSX tag. You are missing a closing `}` for the  `constructor` method. It's difficulty to help if we don't know which of these issues are actual issues.

Comment: Well, there are a few issues in your code: you miss the closing `}` for the constructor method, your `cangeBackground()` function implementation does not make sense, your `<button onClick={/* ... */}/>` prop is not set properly. Frankly speaking, it seems like you just throw some "random" (kind of) code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `changeBackground` should not return anything. Instead, it should `setState` with a new randomly generated `backgruond`, which is a hex string representing RGB color.

```
  changeBackground() {
    let background = "#" + ((1<<24)*Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
    this.setState({background});
  }
```

Then, you need to style your background using `state.background`. Here I return the `div` component as background filling entire view port.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{
        width: '100vw',
        height: '100vh',
        backgroundColor: this.state.background
      }}> 
        <button onClick={this.changeBackground}/>
      </div>
    )   
  }
}
```

Comment: Ive tried backgroundColor: this.state.background it says ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Comment: @MoMiah Make sure that you have `this.state` in `constructor`. And, also make sure that you used double braces; `{{` and `}}`.

Comment: const styles = {
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    height: '100vh',
    alignItems: 'center',
    background : this.state.background
  }
}


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      quotes: [],
      selectedQuoteIndex: null,
      background: 'blue'
    }

Comment: @MoMiah In that case, `this.state ...` must precedes `const style ...`.

Comment: I put the const styles inside the app class but now it is saying that styles is undefined

Comment: @MoMiah That is out of bound, however, if you update your code, I will try to help.

Comment: I managed to fix it but thanks for the random color generator example!

Comment: @MoMiah Only that? I had tested before I wrote the post. That's weird...

Comment: Check out my full code below and lmk what you think? https://github.com/moemia12/randomQuoteMachine/blob/main/src/App.js

Comment: @MoMiah You did not define `onClick`. Add the line `onClick={() => {this.backgroundQuoteChange()}}` as attribute of the `<div ...>Random Quote Machine</div>`. Then you can click the `<div>` and change the background color, buddy. :)